# How does clustering inherit predefined variables in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have this code

```
var running = false;
var cluster = require('cluster');
if(cluster.isMaster){
    cluster.fork();
    running = true;
}
```

In each of my forks, would running be true or false?

Comment: The idea is that the code in this module is executed separately in a separate process for each clustered process.  The only thing that is different is that only one of them gets `cluster.isMaster` set to `true`.  So, you can just see how the code would execute when `cluster.isMaster` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your forks aren't master, so I believe `running` would be `false` since they skip the `if` branch.

Edit: Just making sure, but a quick test found these results:

```
var running = false;
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    cluster.fork();
    cluster.fork();
    cluster.fork();
    running = true;
}

console.log('Master?', cluster.isMaster);
console.log('Running?', running);
```

Output:

```
Master? true
Running? true
Master? false
Running? false
Master? false
Master? false
Running? false
Running? false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit extended version of your code:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var cpus = require('os').cpus().length;

var running = false;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cpus; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
        running = true;
    }
}

console.log('running: '+ running);
```

and here's the result:

```
running: true
running: false
running: false
running: false
running: false
```

In this example, the first line is the master process, and other four lines are the child processes. There're four of them, because my CPU has 4 cores. This can be 1 or 8 or anything else according to the machine that the code runs on.

You can find more information about Node.js clusters here: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html